# navbar responsiva nao aparece quando mudo o tamanho da janela

Tags: javascript, funções, grid, layout-responsivo

Estou fazendo um header completo com grid. O problema é que eu fiz um hamburguer menu. Entao fiz esta funcao para ao clicar ele aparecer e ao clicar novamente ele esconder. Porem se eu aumento a janela(resize) depois de clicar no icone para esconder, ele continua escondido( nao aparece o nav). Quero que ao aumentar a janela este comando da funçao nao funcione. Ou volte para display:grid;

```js
function icondisplay() {
    var iconmenu = document.querySelector('#menuicon i');
    var header = document.querySelector('header');
    var nav = document.querySelector('nav');
    if ((header.style.gridTemplateRows == '1fr 2fr') || (nav.style.display == 'grid')) {
        header.style.gridTemplateRows = '';
        nav.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {
        header.style.gridTemplateRows = '1fr 2fr';
        nav.style.display = 'grid';
    }

}
```

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
 nav{
    display: none;
    grid-row: 2/3;
    grid-column: 1/3;
     margin: 0;
 }
 header{
    grid-template-columns:50% auto;
    justify-items: center;
 }
 ul{ 
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows:repeat(4,1fr);
    grid-row-gap: 50px;
}
#menuicon{
    display: grid;
    align-content: center;
}
```

```html
        <header>
            <div id="logo">
                <img src="img/coin.gif" alt="">
            </div>
            <div id="menuicon"><i onclick="icondisplay(this)" class="fas fa-bars fa-3x"></i></div>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li>Início</li>
                    <li>Produtos</li>
                    <li>Contato</li>
                    <li>Sobre</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
```

Answer (score 1):

Consegui ! 
Procurei muito e vi que dava pra utilizar resize !
Aqui a soluçao.

```
window.onresize = function () {
    if (window.innerWidth > 480) {
        nav.style.display = 'grid';
        header.style.gridTemplateRows = '';
    }
    else { nav.style.display = 'none'; 
    header.style.gridTemplateRows = ''; }

};
```